# What is the decision on my paper?

Tags: journals, peer-review, paper-submission, journal-workflow

I submitted the revised version of my paper to a journal. after two weeks the paper status changed from under review to reviews completed. and still remains in this state about 10 days. What do you think is the decision on my paper? Reject or accept?

Answer (score 5):

> What do you think is the decision on my paper? Reject or accept?

Decision pending. Likely, this means that the review phase of the paper is finished, and is currently awaiting a final verdict by the associate editor or editor-in-chief.